# Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './assets'

Tags: node.js, koa

After setting up [koa-static-folder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-static-folder), my image loads great when I test over localhost with http://localhost:3000/assets/myimage.jpg

But after deploying our node code to an Ubuntu server, we get:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './assets'
```

What's Ubuntu's issue here?  Not sure how to resolve this.

The code that is working locally is:

```
var koa = require('koa')(),
serve = require('koa-static-folder');

koa.use(serve('./assets'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permission issue (but I could be wrong!) such that the user that node.js is running under does not have access rights to the `assets` folder. If this is the problem you have to change access permissions to the folder  ([see chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)) or run node.js as a user that has the access rights.

If the server isn't publicly accessible you could run the application as `sudo` to verify if it is a permissions problem or not. **Note that using sudo is not a long term solution since it is highly irresponsible/unsecure to run the application as the root user.**